# Configuration file for checkpatch.pl tool

Tags: linux-kernel, code-formatting

According to the explanation from [this source](https://github.com/webispy/checkpatch-action#checkpatchpl-configuration), the `.checkpatch.conf` file that specifies the configuration options for `checkpatch.pl` tool must be in the top-level directory of the project.
Would it be possible that we put `checkpatch.conf` on some other location and somehow specify the path to it in `checkpatch.pl` (or somewhere else)?

I tried to do it the following way in `checkpatch.pl` file:

```perl
my $configuration_file = "<path_to_the>/.checkpatch.conf";
```

but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, in addition to (or perhaps instead of) changing the value assigned to the **$configuration_file** variable, you need to slightly alter the **which_conf** subroutine.

The original sub routine is:

```perl
sub which_conf {
    my ($conf) = @_;

    foreach my $path (split(/:/, ".:$ENV{HOME}:.scripts")) {
        if (-e "$path/$conf") {
            return "$path/$conf";
        }
    }

    return "";
}
```

this takes a configuration file name as input and returns the path to the first occurrence of the file found in a list of predefined directories. Here's how it works:

- It receives the filename ($conf) as an argument.
- It iterates over a list of directories (".:$ENV{HOME}:.scripts"), separated by colons.
- For each directory, it checks if the configuration file exists by appending the directory and filename together ("$path/$conf") and using the -e file test operator.
- If the file is found, the subroutine immediately returns the path to the file.
- If no file is found in any of the directories, an empty string is returned.

So it's likely the reason that simply changing the value of $configuration_file does not work is because it's getting evaluated as /some/base/path/<path_to_the>/.checkpatch.conf which will not exist.

I would try instead of altering $configuration_file variable at all, adding the base path you want it to search to find your checkpatch.conf file using a colon as a delimiter.

```perl
foreach my $path (split(/:/, ".:$ENV{HOME}:.scripts:./my/sub/path"))
```

or

```perl
foreach my $path (split(/:/, ".:$ENV{HOME}:.scripts:/my/full/path"))
```